# Im trying to make this table in the tabular environment but i can't get the titles in the right place

Tags: tables

I am trying to make the following table [image]

but I don't want it to overlap the text that I have placed.
This is what shows up in my document 
[image]

This is what I wrote so far

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\caption{}
\label{table:1}


\begin{tabular} {|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{II/446} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{II/444}\\
    \hline
    Threshold Value & Circumscribed & Osculating & Circumscribed & 
    Osculating \\
    of radius & circle & circle & circle & circle \\
    \hline
    100\%  & 65\% & 65\% & 54\% & 56\% \\
    \hline
    300\%  & 73\% & 72\% & 74\% & 76\% \\
    \hline
    500\%  & 74\% & 73\% & 80\% & 80\% \\
    \hline
    1000\% & 70\% & 78\% & 80\% & 81\% \\
    \hline
    1500\% & 70\% & 74\% & 78\% & 80\% \\
    \hline
    2000\% & 72\% & 75\% & 77\% & 78\% \\
    \hline



\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Remember that ``\\`` is **not** new line inside a table, it means **new row**, so perhaps look at the titles as cells and put  `Treshold Value &  Circumscribed & Osculating & ...` on a row of its own, then `of radius & circle & ...` as the next row.

Comment: @daleif thnx that helped but right now its overlapping the text even more

Comment: With the information you currently provide, the issue you describe is not reproducible. Could you therefore please provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get? Also, how is the question related to the `tabularx` package that you don't seem to use for this table?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but you might want to replace  `& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{II/446} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{II/444}` by  `& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{II/446} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{II/444}`  as the former leads to double vertical lines in the header row. Also unrelated, but it might be better to replace the `center`  environment by the `\centering` command as the former adds additional vertical white space around the table.

Comment: I only get very little overflow if I add it to a sample doc. So as others have mentioned, please provide a full but minimal example instead of just a sniplet like this.

Comment: Nothing you've shown here could possibly lead to your table being partially covered by "An [artistic?] network [of] many black- Germans".  For future questions, please provide us enough to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on guessing, that your table is in two column document and it is wider than one column. Consequently, it overlaps with the second column.

If you not like to have table over two columns (with use of `figure*` float environment), than you must make your table narrower. One way is use abbreviation for column header:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage{xparse} % for "smart" new commands
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{c|}m}
    {\multicolumn{1}{#1}{#2}}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}  % for dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{}
    \label{table:1}
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{|c<{\,m}|*{4}{c<{\,\%}|}}
    \hline
\mcc[|p{6.6em}|]{%
    \multirow{2}{=}{\centering
                    Threshold Value of radius}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{II/446} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{II/444}\\
    \cline{2-5}
\mcc[|c|]{}
        & \mcc{CC}  & \mcc{OC}  & \mcc{CC}   & \mcc{OC}    \\
    \hline
100   & 65    & 65    & 54    & 56    \\
    \hline
300  & 73 & 72 & 74 & 76 \\
    \hline
500  & 74 & 73 & 80 & 80 \\
    \hline
1000 & 70 & 78 & 80 & 81 \\
    \hline
1500 & 70 & 74 & 78 & 80 \\
    \hline
2000 & 72 & 75 & 77 & 78 \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{CC: Circumscribed circle,\quad
OC: Osculating circle}
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[2-5]
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: @Zyzzx I recommend to show the helper appreciation by upvoting a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following layout to fix the overflow of text

```
    \begin{table}[]
\caption{}
\label{foo-bar}
\resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{II/446} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{II/444} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Threshold value \\ of radius (m)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Circumscribed\\ circle\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Osculating\\ circle\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Circumscribed\\ circle\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Osculating\\ circle\end{tabular} \\ \hline
100\%  & 65\% & 65\% & 54\% & 56\% \\
\hline
300\%  & 73\% & 72\% & 74\% & 76\% \\
\hline
500\%  & 74\% & 73\% & 80\% & 80\% \\
\hline
1000\% & 70\% & 78\% & 80\% & 81\% \\
\hline
1500\% & 70\% & 74\% & 78\% & 80\% \\
\hline
2000\% & 72\% & 75\% & 77\% & 78\% \\
\hline

\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
```

and this code produced this in my document with, again, no overflow
[image]

Comment: Please, explain in what differ your answer in comparison to the code in question? In cells' contents align only? Nor your question nor answer we cant test to see, what really  is your problem. You always need to provide MWE, a complete small compilable document.

Comment: It looks like the main difference is `\resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}{ ... }`.  This is a very blunt way to solve your problem that has various consequences that you should be aware of.