# How to create the table shown in the figure?

Tags: tables

[image]

It contains damage parameters of a building.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please add a minimal example of what you tried so far?

Comment: There are nothing special in this  table, except the use of `\multicolumn` and `\multirow` commands for some cells, and the horrendous vertical lines and excess of horizontal rules. There are plenty of examples  on this site of both commands, and about the package `booktabs` to  avoid the jailed tables.

Comment: for start see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables. similar table with less columns you can se here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492079/im-trying-to-make-this-table-in-the-tabular-environment-but-i-cant-get-the-titl/492152#492152

Answer (score 1):

The table can be recreated like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{text}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{S.NO} & \multirow{2}{*}{Building ID} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{FO} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{IO} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{LS} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{CP}\\
\cline{3-10}
& & $\mu$ & $\sigma$ &$\mu$ & $\sigma$ &$\mu$ & $\sigma$ &$\mu$ & $\sigma$ \\
\hline
1 & G+3 & 4.2 & 19.3 & 4.2 & 19.3 & 4.2 & 19.3 & 4.2 & 19.3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]